# Disable normal mode in ex (vim -e)

Tags: vim, mode, ex

I have to use ex (or "vim -e"), because normal mode does not work in one of my environments.

If I start ex, the following message appear "Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.". Is it possible, to

- remove this unnecessary text (if I could use normal mode I wouldn't use ex mode)
- disable normal mode at all (so that if I enter "vi", nothing happens)

*Note: fixed the text (I wrote visual mode instead of normal previously)*

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I wrote normal mode 3 times, but visual for the 4th, because you have to type "visual" to get into "normal" mode :). Normal mode cannot be used if you do not have a terminal (you can just use stdin and stdout - e.g. in case of a chroot w/o bash).

Answer (score 2):

> remove this unnecessary text (if I could use normal mode I wouldn't use ex mode)

That text is only unnecessary because of your normal mode issue. If you want a Vim tailored around your exact circumstances you will have to change the source and compile your own Vim.

Or fix the underlying issue.

> disable visual mode at all (so that if I enter "vi", nothing happens)

`:vi` doesn't enter visual mode, it enters normal mode. If by "visual mode" you mean "the fullscreen TUI also known as `vi`", then no, it can't be disabled but, if you don't want that feature, why do you do `:vi` to begin with?

If your fingers don't agree with your brain, then you may be able to fool them with a mapping.

Comment: I wrote "visual mode" mistakenly, because you have to type **"visual"** ("vi") command to get into **normal** mode from ex. My bad, but this solution is also confusing in vim.
Anyway, thanks (I was hoping that there is an easier solution on that :) )

Answer (score 0):

Can't you start Ex with `ex` instad of `vim -e`? For me, doing so prevents the message.

Comment: If it works for you this is seemingly not a constant, `ex` for me results in the "Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode."  prompt

Comment: I use "ex", but the result is the same (on Debian)